# Confirmation message when submitting post for review

Tags: post-editor

If a someone submit a post for review, I want to show a message, something like:

> Your post has been submitted successfully. Thank you.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are they submitting the post through the standard dashboard interface (i.e. `/wp-admin/post-new.php`)?

Comment: What does "submit a post for review" mean? Afaik this isn't standard functionality of WP

Comment: @bosco yes. Through the standard dashboard interface.

Comment: @kero this is standard functionality of WP. Contributor role has the ability to write post, not publish them. They submit for review.